# Overload a Flask block?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Let's say I have a few levels of inheritance with my templates: index.html extends base_additional.html which extends base.html. In base.html, I have:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
```

and in base_additional.html, I want to append some standard text, say " - My Site" to the end of whatever is in `{% block title %}` in index.html. How can I do this without doing something like `{% block title2 %}`? Basically, I want to create a middle-man template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use Jinja's [`super`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#super-blocks) function.

By calling it inside the block in a child template (`index.html`), you retain whatever was inside the block in the parent template (`base_addition.html`).

index.html

```
{% extends 'base_additional.html' %}

{% block title %}Page's Title{{super()}}{% endblock %}
```

base_additional.html

```
<title>{% block title %} - My Site{% endblock %}
```

This will result in

```
<title>Page's Title - My Site</title>
```

Comment: Thanks, @dirn. I was hoping for a way to do this without index.html having to know to call super() itself (thus the want to overload the block), but this will work.